# prevent copy if pdf document (generated from word)

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I'm a converting my Word document into pdf using the built-in microsoft office converter (save as--> pdf).

I want my pdf to be protected (users cannot copy text from it). i can't seem to find any options for this when converting to pdf.

Any hint?

Thanks.

Comment: Please don't do this.  It's extremely annoying to have to use OCR just to copy and paste a snippet of text.

Comment: What does this have to do with programming?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it, Can be done with Adobe Acrobat Professional, not the Acrobat Reader.

PDF, or portable document format, forms were created by Adobe as a form of universal file format. Adobe Acrobat Reader, which allows you to view PDF files, is available for free download. Unfortunately, to manipulate documents and perform functions like changing security settings, you must have the full Adobe Acrobat software. With it, you can create secure PDFs, but you can also change security settings on PDF forms.

Comment: you can use "LibreOffice" as free alternative to Acrobat Pro XI.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ***export to PDF*** feature in **LibreOffice**, just set permission password and then **disable Content Copying**.

[image]